# What is the Maximum value for Java Duration

Tags: java, java-8, max, java-7, duration

I tried to create a max Duration in Java 8 by using Duration.ofMillis(Long.MAX_VALUE) but got a long overflow.
How would I programmatically get the equivalent of a Duration.MAX_VALUE if it existed?

Edit: The long overflow was likely caused by an attempt to add to the value instead of during construction. Apologies for not having reproducible code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple:

```
Duration maxDur = ChronoUnit.FOREVER.getDuration();
```

Comment: Wow, no idea this existed, definitely what I was looking for way back when

Comment: which is defined as `FOREVER("Forever", Duration.ofSeconds(Long.MAX_VALUE, 999_999_999))` and documented as "... The estimated duration of this unit is artificially defined as the **largest duration supported by Duration**."

Answer (score 9):

It looks like `Duration` is stored in seconds (up to `Long.MAX_VALUE`) and nanoseconds (up to `999,999,999`). Then the biggest duration possible is:

```java
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds(Long.MAX_VALUE, 999_999_999);
```

When I print it (`System.out.print(d)`) I get the following:

```
PT2562047788015215H30M7.999999999S
```

which means: 2562047788015215 hours, 30 minutes, and 7.999999999 seconds.

Comment: seconds can be negative so it should be `Long.MIN_VALUE..LONG.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: That duration is equivalent to around 292 billion years.

Comment: While this does produce the highest java.time.Duration, java.time already provides this with `ChronoUnit.FOREVER`.  See my [succinct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549713/2812695).

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html):

> The duration uses nanosecond resolution with a maximum value of the seconds that can be held in a long.
>
> The range of a duration requires the storage of a number larger than a long. To achieve this, the class stores a long representing seconds and an int representing nanosecond-of-second, which will always be between 0 and 999,999,999. The model is of a directed duration, meaning that the duration may be negative.

Comment: So why would Long.MAX_VALUE cause an overflow? What is the maximum value allowed for the Seconds portion?

Comment: well, I just tried this piece of code: `Duration test = Duration.ofMillis(Long.MAX_VALUE);`and I don't get an overflow.  Could you show the code that throws the exception?

Comment: I no longer have it sorry. You know, it must have been caused later when something was added to it.